# Texture atlas renders differently on a different computer

Tags: java, opengl, texture-mapping

I'm having a problem with a simple 2d tile-based engine I'm working on. On my home computer (Windows 7 64bit, jogl 1.1.1) the textures bind properly to the tiles but on my laptop (Windows Vidta 32bit, jogl 1.1.1) they appear broken.

The sprites image is 600x100 (each sprite being 100x100).

Here is the textureManager class that I'm using.

```
public class TextureManager {

    private static Texture textureAtlas;
    private static Map<String, TextureCoords> locations;
    private static String imageName;

    public TextureManager() {

        locations = new HashMap<String, TextureCoords>();
    }

    public static void loadAtlas(String name) {

        if(textureAtlas != null) {

            if(imageName == name) return;

            textureAtlas.dispose();
        }

        imageName = name;

        try {

            textureAtlas = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("textures/" + name + ".png"), true);
        }
        catch (GLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setAtlasLocations();
    }

    private static void setAtlasLocations() {

        locations.put("blank", textureAtlas.getSubImageTexCoords(0, 0, 100, 100));
        locations.put("tree1", textureAtlas.getSubImageTexCoords(100, 0, 200, 100));
        locations.put("tree2", textureAtlas.getSubImageTexCoords(200, 0, 300, 100));
        locations.put("tree3", textureAtlas.getSubImageTexCoords(300, 0, 400, 100));
        locations.put("rock", textureAtlas.getSubImageTexCoords(400, 0, 500, 100));
    }

    public static void bindTexture() {

        textureAtlas.bind();
    }

    public static TextureCoords getCoords(String name) {

        return locations.get(name);
    }
}
```

This is the rendering code:

```
    public void draw(GL gl) {

        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        TextureManager.bindTexture();

        int width = map.width();
        int height = map.height();

        float x = InterfaceManager.mapX;
        float y = InterfaceManager.mapY;

        gl.glTranslatef(x, y - height, 0);

        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);

        gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        for(int w = 0; w < width; w++) {

            for(int h = 0; h < height; h++) {

                TextureCoords coords = getCoord(map.getTileType(w, h));

                gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.left(), coords.bottom());
                gl.glVertex3i(w, h, 0);
                gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.right(), coords.bottom());
                gl.glVertex3i(w+1, h, 0);
                gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.right(), coords.top());
                gl.glVertex3i(w+1, h+1, 0);
                gl.glTexCoord2f(coords.left(), coords.top());
                gl.glVertex3i(w, h+1, 0);
            }
        }

        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glTranslatef(-x, -y + height, 0);

        gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    private TextureCoords getCoord(int tileType) {

        if(tileType == 0) return TextureManager.getCoords("blank");
        else if(tileType == 1) return TextureManager.getCoords("rock");
        else if(tileType == 2) return TextureManager.getCoords("tree1");
        else if(tileType == 3) return TextureManager.getCoords("tree2");
        else if(tileType == 4) return TextureManager.getCoords("tree3");
        else return TextureManager.getCoords("blank");
    }
```

I know opengl is supposed to be platform independent, and since I'm using the same versions of opengl on both, I'm assuming there's probably a bug in my code.

Hopefully someone more experienced with it can help me out with this problem. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a picture of the skewed result.

[image: screwedTexture]

The trees along the top and right side is actually supposed to be the rock in the sprite below.

This is the sprite file:

[image]

Comment: How do they appear broken? Can you put an image? It would help to diagnose.

Comment: I've edited to include some images!

Comment: Hmm sorry nothing coming to mind yet. Maybe throw in a glGetError if you aren't currently checking for it? I don't know if that will catch anything or not, but sometimes it can help you spot funky problems that mess up your render in weird ways.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Ok, now i feel bad. This is the second time that I've figured out my problem shortly after posting the question. My sprite file doesn't mipmap correctly. when i turn automatically mipmap off, it works. I'll have to figure out how to make a sprite file that mipmaps correctly. Thanks though Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatically generated mipmaps by OpenGL were causing the problem. Changing the below line to not allow auto mipmapping fixes the problem.

```
textureAtlas = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("textures/" + name + ".png"), false);
```

If anyone would like to comment on how i should create my sprite file to allow auto mipmapping, or if this should even be on, please do :)

With mipmapping off, as i move the character around, some tiles get a black line beneath them. I'll have to figure out how to make the sprite image mipmap-able.

EDIT: Make the file square and to the power of 2.